PowerShell cmdlets not available within a script unless it is run as administrator
I wonder if somebody can help with this issue.  Essentially I want to be able to connect to Exchange Online and the Security and Compliance PowerShell from within a script run as a regular user, not administrator.
If I drop these commands into my un-elevated PS window they will connect successfully and give me back some info on the two commands.  If I drop the same commands into a PS1 file and execute it in an elevated PS console they also run successfully.
Connect-IPPSSession
Get-Command Get-DlpCompliancePolicy
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Get-Command Get-Mailbox

However if I drop those commands into a PS1 file and run from an unelevated PS1 session I get errors like 'get-command : The term 'get-dlpcompliancepolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program'.
If I run Get-ConnectionInformation in the script I can see the two connections are there -
ConnectionId                    : 745f6176-5d1f-46ec-a786-b8e84f273791
State                           : Connected
Id                              : 1
Name                            : ExchangeOnlineProtection_1
UserPrincipalName               : *********
ConnectionUri                   : https://eur01b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com
AzureAdAuthorizationEndpointUri : https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations
TokenExpiryTimeUTC              : 20/04/2024 10:01:24 +00:00
CertificateAuthentication       : False
ModuleName                      : C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_5lnrtren.etr
ModulePrefix                    :
Organization                    :
DelegatedOrganization           :
AppId                           :
PageSize                        : 1000
TenantID                        : 081cc50b-e5a5-4e76-b6b7-d7c274899193
TokenStatus                     : Active
ConnectionUsedForInbuiltCmdlets : False
IsEopSession                    : True

ConnectionId                    : 3d3547ec-f35e-4dc3-ba50-ed2f93ef0c35
State                           : Connected
Id                              : 2
Name                            : ExchangeOnline_2
UserPrincipalName               : *******
ConnectionUri                   : https://outlook.office365.com
AzureAdAuthorizationEndpointUri : https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations
TokenExpiryTimeUTC              : 20/04/2024 11:50:29 +00:00
CertificateAuthentication       : False
ModuleName                      : C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_a2axh3gk.iwh
ModulePrefix                    :
Organization                    :
DelegatedOrganization           :
AppId                           :
PageSize                        : 1000
TenantID                        : 081cc50b-e5a5-4e76-b6b7-d7c274899193
TokenStatus                     : Active
ConnectionUsedForInbuiltCmdlets : True
IsEopSession                    : False

If I run Get-Module I can see the modules I understand are necessary -
Name              : ExchangeOnlineManagement
Path              : C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.4.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnli
                    neManagement.psm1
Description       : This is a General Availability (GA) release of the Exchange Online Powershell V3 module. Exchange
                    Online cmdlets in this module are REST-backed and do not require Basic Authentication to be
                    enabled in WinRM. REST-based connections in Windows require the PowerShellGet module, and by
                    dependency, the PackageManagement module.
                    Please check the documentation here - https://aka.ms/exov3-module.
                    For issues related to the module, contact Microsoft support.
Guid              : b5eced50-afa4-455b-847a-d8fb64140a22
Version           : 3.4.0
ModuleBase        : C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.4.0
ModuleType        : Script
PrivateData       : {PSData}
AccessMode        : ReadWrite
ExportedAliases   : {}
ExportedCmdlets   : {[Add-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy, Add-VivaModuleFeaturePolicy], [Get-ConnectionInformation,
                    Get-ConnectionInformation], [Get-DefaultTenantBriefingConfig, Get-DefaultTenantBriefingConfig],
                    [Get-DefaultTenantMyAnalyticsFeatureConfig, Get-DefaultTenantMyAnalyticsFeatureConfig]...}
ExportedFunctions : {[Connect-ExchangeOnline, Connect-ExchangeOnline], [Connect-IPPSSession, Connect-IPPSSession],
                    [Disconnect-ExchangeOnline, Disconnect-ExchangeOnline]}
ExportedVariables : {}
NestedModules     : {Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient,
                    Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule}

Name              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Path              : C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerS
                    hell.Management.psd1
Description       :
Guid              : eefcb906-b326-4e99-9f54-8b4bb6ef3c6d
Version           : 3.1.0.0
ModuleBase        : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
ModuleType        : Manifest
PrivateData       :
AccessMode        : ReadWrite
ExportedAliases   : {[gcb, gcb], [gin, gin], [gtz, gtz], [scb, scb]...}
ExportedCmdlets   : {[Add-Computer, Add-Computer], [Add-Content, Add-Content], [Checkpoint-Computer,
                    Checkpoint-Computer], [Clear-Content, Clear-Content]...}
ExportedFunctions : {}
ExportedVariables : {}
NestedModules     : {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll}

Name              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Path              : C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShel
                    l.Utility.psd1
Description       :
Guid              : 1da87e53-152b-403e-98dc-74d7b4d63d59
Version           : 3.1.0.0
ModuleBase        : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
ModuleType        : Manifest
PrivateData       :
AccessMode        : ReadWrite
ExportedAliases   : {[CFS, CFS], [fhx, fhx]}
ExportedCmdlets   : {[Add-Member, Add-Member], [Add-Type, Add-Type], [Clear-Variable, Clear-Variable],
                    [Compare-Object, Compare-Object]...}
ExportedFunctions : {[ConvertFrom-SddlString, ConvertFrom-SddlString], [Format-Hex, Format-Hex], [Get-FileHash,
                    Get-FileHash], [Import-PowerShellDataFile, Import-PowerShellDataFile]...}
ExportedVariables : {}
NestedModules     : {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll, Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility}

Name              : PSReadLine
Path              : C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine\2.0.0\PSReadLine.psm1
Description       : Great command line editing in the PowerShell console host
Guid              : 5714753b-2afd-4492-a5fd-01d9e2cff8b5
Version           : 2.0.0
ModuleBase        : C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine\2.0.0
ModuleType        : Script
PrivateData       :
AccessMode        : ReadWrite
ExportedAliases   : {}
ExportedCmdlets   : {[Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler], [Get-PSReadLineOption,
                    Get-PSReadLineOption], [Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler],
                    [Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler]...}
ExportedFunctions : {[PSConsoleHostReadLine, PSConsoleHostReadLine]}
ExportedVariables : {}
NestedModules     : {Microsoft.PowerShell.PSReadLine}

Name              : tmpEXO_5lnrtren.etr
Path              : C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_5lnrtren.etr\tmpEXO_5lnrtren.etr.psm1
Description       : This is a Powershell module generated by using the AutoGEN infra.
Guid              : 2c604488-886e-4090-ac70-2b9a3130c449
Version           : 1.0
ModuleBase        : C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_5lnrtren.etr
ModuleType        : Script
PrivateData       : {PSData}
AccessMode        : ReadWrite
ExportedAliases   : {}
ExportedCmdlets   : {}
ExportedFunctions : {[Add-ComplianceCaseMember, Add-ComplianceCaseMember], [Add-eDiscoveryCaseAdmin,
                    Add-eDiscoveryCaseAdmin], [Add-RoleGroupMember, Add-RoleGroupMember], [Cancel-DlpEdmSession,
                    Cancel-DlpEdmSession]...}
ExportedVariables : {[HelpFileNames, System.Management.Automation.PSVariable]}
NestedModules     : {}

Name              : tmpEXO_a2axh3gk.iwh
Path              : C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_a2axh3gk.iwh\tmpEXO_a2axh3gk.iwh.psm1
Description       : This is a Powershell module generated by using the AutoGEN infra.
Guid              : e84305bc-e9b9-45bd-bb9f-d38a411419b2
Version           : 1.0
ModuleBase        : C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_a2axh3gk.iwh
ModuleType        : Script
PrivateData       : {PSData}
AccessMode        : ReadWrite
ExportedAliases   : {}
ExportedCmdlets   : {}
ExportedFunctions : {[Add-AvailabilityAddressSpace, Add-AvailabilityAddressSpace], [Add-DistributionGroupMember,
                    Add-DistributionGroupMember], [Add-MailboxFolderPermission, Add-MailboxFolderPermission],
                    [Add-MailboxLocation, Add-MailboxLocation]...}
ExportedVariables : {[HelpFileNames, System.Management.Automation.PSVariable]}
NestedModules     : {}

And once the script exits, I can then do 'Get-Command Get-Mailbox' and get a good response.  So the connection is clearly working, the script just cannot seem to access the functions/cmdlets while it is running.  This is Twilight Zone stuff right!?
I do not know if it's relevant, but we use AppLocker.  So in my unelevated PS session I am in ConstrainedLanguage mode, but the script is excluded from AppLocker so executes in FullLanguage mode.
I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about how PS sessions or scopes operate within a script run as admin vs a regular user, or is there a bug in Connect-ExchangeOnline, but no amount of Google searching has saved my mind yet!
Thanks

+1 for clearly stating the issue.

I don't think you actually need to use a connect-pssession anymore. Just use connect-exchangeonline and login with your credentials. Can also be done without elevation. Both commands should then work.

Thanks for responding @LPChip but I'm not using Connect-PSSession and the crux of the issue is that Connect-ExchangeOnline will indeed connect without elevation within a script but none of the commands it exports are available.

To my knowlegdge all those components have merged to ExchangeOnline, maybe you need to run an import module PSOnline (or whatever the name is that holds the commands) first to get the commands.

@music2myear I think your answer is valid, but just needs to import the correct module to get the commands back.

This is a PowerShell profile issue. Determine which profile is being used for each case and update your question

@LPChip I've updated the question to include the output of Get-Module from within the script, I think everything I need is already imported, though I added an Import-Module ExchangeOnline just to be sure but to no effect

@Ramhound could you elaborate a bit please?

@PH2022 I'm fairly sure you need Import-module MSOnline

Its also possible you have an older version of the ExchangeOnline module installed, and that you need to remove it then install latest.

@PH2022 - Providing which PowerShell profile you are using is very basic information there isn’t anything to elaborate

@Ramhound Sorry for not responding sooner.  I have just checked and the PowerShell Profile ($PROFILE) is the same path outside the script as when I execute the script.  Is that what you wanted me to check?

Thanks @LPChip.  I've added the output of Get-Module to the question, the latest version of ExchangeOnlineManagement is being used unfortunately.  I don't think MSOnline is required, that's the old deprecated module by the looks of it.
